# sitecore federated authentication GetOwinContext() doesn't have authenticated user info

Tags: federated-authentication, owin

I am using `Federated Authentication` for external users login (`Sitecore version 9.2`)
After the user is authenticated, User.Identity has is `external\anonymous` and doesn't have the claims returned by the login provider same for `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Identity` as well.

However, `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie")` returns correct identity and claims

Is there any Sitecore's pipeline/process that is causing so? Any insights to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your Federated Authentication setup it's a bit hard to guess what might be the problem.

Could you check in the SecurityTokenValidatedAsync event what your identity is?

For example:

```
public async Task SecurityTokenValidatedAsync(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    // What type of identity do you have here?
    var identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
}
```

There could also be a misconfiguration in your owin config. Here an example which I'm using and works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
                <mapEntry name="sites with extranet domain" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true" patch:instead="*[@name='sites with extranet domain']">
                    <sites hint="list">
                        <site>project</site>
                    </sites>
                    <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
                        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='ProjectIdentityProvider']" />
                    </identityProviders>
                    <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
                        <IsPersistentUser>false</IsPersistentUser>
                    </externalUserBuilder>
                </mapEntry>
            </identityProvidersPerSites>
            <identityProviders>
                <identityProvider id="ProjectIdentityProvider" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                    <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
                    <caption>Go to login</caption>
                    <domain>extranet</domain>
                    <triggerExternalSignOut>true</triggerExternalSignOut>
                    <!--list of identity transfromations which are applied to the provider when a user signin-->
                    <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
                        <!--SetIdpClaim transformation-->
                        <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                        <!-- If external authentication is configured with "TokenValidationParameters = {SaveSigninToken = true}", this saves the value from "claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext" to the "id_token" claim. -->
                        <transformation name="set id_token claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SaveIdTokenInClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
                    </transformations>
                </identityProvider>
            </identityProviders>
        </federatedAuthentication>
        <pipelines>
            <owin.identityProviders>
                <processor type="Project.Foundation.Identity.IdentityProviders.ProjectIdentityProvider, Project.Foundation.Identity" resolve="true" id="ProjectIdentityProvider">
                    <scopes hint="list">
                        <scope name="openid">openid</scope>
                        <scope name="sitecore.profile">sitecore.profile</scope>
                    </scopes>
                </processor>
            </owin.identityProviders>

            <owin.initialize help="Processors should derive from Sitecore.Owin.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeProcessor">
                <processor name="CookieAuthentication" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.Initialize.CookieAuthentication, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
                           resolve="true" patch:before="processor[@method='Authenticate']">
                    <ExpireTimeSpan>01:00:00</ExpireTimeSpan>
                    <SlidingExpiration>true</SlidingExpiration>
                </processor>
            </owin.initialize>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

I hope this helps.